# How to Isolate Rows of a Table Given One Column Using Two Variables

Tags: excel, datatable, row

So I want to isolate all of the rows that are labeled 'Good' from all the rows that are labeled "bad".

I've tried to use the 'sort and filter' tool in excel, but this hasn't worked, I think due to the presence of the index table, which I've used to generate my formulas.

Here are the formulas being used to obtain a unique number for each row, which I then use to determine whether a value is "good" or "bad".

For reference, not all the boxes in the spreadsheet that are green are labeled 'good'.

[image: Cell Showing the formula for determining if a row is "good" or "bad"][image: Cell Showing the formula for index lookup, and generating a unique eruption number]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using an if statement and matching to the relevant number in the table, then printing the corresponding column data. This will need to be repeated for each column of data you want to use. An example of the code is given below;

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,AB:AB,0)),AG:AG,"No Data")